# Kubectl: How to grep exceptions out of multiple pods?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I would love to have a way to use kubectl to filter exception from a bunch of pods.

For example, suppose I have the following pods:

```
Service-1-1
Service-1-2
Service-1-3
Service-1-4
```

Until now I moved one by one and executed:

```
k logs Service-1-1 | grep exception
k logs Service-1-2 | grep exception
k logs Service-1-3 | grep exception
k logs Service-1-4 | grep exception
```

Can I have a joined filtering for all of pods at once?

Comment: you can pull those like this : `kubectl -n <NAMESPACE> logs -f service/<YOUR_SERVICE_NAME> --all-containers=true`, I guess

Answer (score 2):

If the pods have a subset of labels you can filter them with, then you can use a label selector to do so.

Let's say all 4 pods have the label: `app: service` (and no other pods have the same label) then you can run:

```
kubectl logs -l app=service | grep exception
```

See documentation here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#logs

Comment: Thank you @whites11. Interesting... When I execute     k logs -l app=myservicename    ,  I get lots of exceptions in the output. When I execute    k logs -l app=trafficmanager | grep exception       - I get nothing... Why does that happen?

Comment: you can check what pods match your query with `kubectl get po -l app=yourselector` if that helps

Comment: Strange...     kubectl get po -l app=myservicename     gives me other pods that I get when I execute     kubectl get pods --show-labels | grep=myservicename    What's the meaning??? I thought I should use the service label...

Comment: to be clearer kubectl get po -l app=service resulted with Service-1-5 and
Service-1-6